# Flutter, error en google sign sólo cuando genero el appbundle en apk funciona

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo la app subida para testearla desde la google play console.
El problema es que el registro mediante google sign lanza un error sólo cuando genero desde appbundle, desde apk funciona y desde visual studio code también.
El error es:
`platformexception(sign_in_failed, k4.a: 10: null null)`

Haciendo pruebas la línea que falla es:
`final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();`

He comprobado el SHA en debug, release y el Certificado de la clave de firma de aplicación, pero no sé por donde tirar porque parece todo bien.

La función a la que llamo es esta:

```
Future<AuthenticationRequest> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    AuthenticationRequest authRequest = AuthenticationRequest();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context);

    try {
      progressDialog.show();

      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? authentication = await googleUser!.authentication;

      final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: authentication!.idToken,
        accessToken: authentication.accessToken,
      );

      final UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      user = userCredential.user!;

      authRequest.succes = true;
      progressDialog.dismiss();

    } catch (e) {
      progressDialog.dismiss();
      authRequest.succes = false;
    }
    return authRequest;
  }
```

Muchas Gracias por la posible ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El error que muestras es una APIExeption:

> platformexception(sign_in_failed, k4.a: 10: null null)

de acuerdo a lo que comentas :

> El problema es que el registro mediante google sign lanza un error
> sólo cuando genero desde appbundle, desde apk funciona y desde visual
> studio code también.

Lo màs probable es que sea un problema de configuraciòn de la API.

**Cualquier API que uses en tu aplicaciòn debe configurarse con el SHA-1 (o SHA-256) del certificado con el cual firmas tu aplicaciòn a Google Play**, no debes usar el certificado de debug (`debug.keystore`), obten el SHA del certificado con el que firmas tu app para Google Play y usalo para configurar tu OAuth client ID.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por contestar, he comprobado las 3 claves, la debug, la release y la del certificado de la play console. Estan las tres metidas en el sdk de firebase y el google-service.json cargado de nuevo y haciendo clean en el proyecto. Pero no hay manera.

Comment: el .AAB o el .APK que debes usar es el que se genera como "release" y se crea dentro del directorio /release , asegura que en tu API tengas definido el SHA del certificado con el que firmas tu app en Google Play.  Estaba pensado si tal vez estabas usando "Flavors", agrega tu archivo build.gradle por favor

Comment: He estado de viaje y no he podido contestar, como siempre fallo tonto, el problema venía del certificado que genera la Google play. Gracias por la ayuda.